# ValueError: multiclass format is not supported for average_precision_score

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to calculate the average precision score for my object detection predicted labels with the ground truth labels using scikit-learn library. However, I get an error while I try to run the code.

```py
    y_pred = np.array([106, 86, 115, 92])
    y_truth = np.array([105, 85, 114, 91])
    average_precision_score(y_pred, y_truth)
```

The error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/home/lunet/conm/Desktop/Stenosis-Project/vgg16_pre_weights.ipynb Cell 34 in <cell line: 38>()
    115     y_pred = np.array([106, 86, 115, 92])
    116     y_truth = np.array([105, 85, 114, 91])
--> 117     average_precision_score(y_pred, y_truth)
    118     i = i + 1
    119 plt.show()

File ~/Mambaforge-Linux-x86_64/envs/stenosispy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_ranking.py:234, in average_precision_score(y_true, y_score, average, pos_label, sample_weight)
    227         raise ValueError(
    228             f"pos_label={pos_label} is not a valid label. It should be "
    229             f"one of {present_labels}"
    230         )
    231 average_precision = partial(
    232     _binary_uninterpolated_average_precision, pos_label=pos_label
    233 )
--> 234 return _average_binary_score(
    235     average_precision, y_true, y_score, average, sample_weight=sample_weight
    236 )

File ~/Mambaforge-Linux-x86_64/envs/stenosispy/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/_base.py:72, in _average_binary_score(binary_metric, y_true, y_score, average, sample_weight)
     70 y_type = type_of_target(y_true)
     71 if y_type not in ("binary", "multilabel-indicator"):
---> 72     raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
     74 if y_type == "binary":
     75     return binary_metric(y_true, y_score, sample_weight=sample_weight)

ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Average precision is basically the area under precision/recall curve. It operates on scores (e.g. `predict_proba()` results or pre-argmax'ed NN outputs), not predicted labels.
Additionally, in a multiclass case you'll likely need to run `label_binarize()` on `y_truth`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did try the label_binarize() function. It still does not show any difference for the error. ```y_truth = label_binarize(y_truth, classes=[0, 1, 2, 3])```. I am not sure if this is the correct way to use this though since I have not used this function before.

Comment: You'll need probability output as well. Perhaps if you shared more of your code, I could give a more precise advice.

Comment: So I have a model trained and saved which I then load to show my predictions using code from here: https://keras.io/examples/vision/object_detection_using_vision_transformer/#evaluate-the-model this prints out the predicted and ground truth labels. I want to find the AP with these labels. This is my code: https://hastebin.com/fagugeyude.properties, same from the Keras link with the AP implementation at the end with comments using the prediction and ground truth labels. Hope it is clear. Thanks!

Comment: I see, those aren't labels, this is a bounding box. That's not so easy then, but you still need to extract the confidence score of the detection. I believe sklearn routine should work if you supply the data like this: `y_truth = [1 if respective IoU >= 0.5 (or whatever is the threshold of your choice) else 0]`, `y_pred = [confidence scores]`.

Comment: Oh alright, is the confidence scores the predicted bounding boxes?